# Trying to access an API using Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having some trouble trying to access an API to get or fetch data. I'm still currently new to `vue.js` and `javascript`. I'm getting an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer`. I can't seem to understand what the error means or seems to indicate.

```
<body>
    <div id="vue-app">
          {{ articles }}
    </div>
<body>
```

---

```
var article = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',

    data: {
        articles = ''
    },

    created: function () {
        this.fetchData();
    },        

    methods: {
        fetchData: function () {
            var that = this
            this.$http.get('localhost/aim-beta/rest/export/json/article'),
                function (data) {
                    vm.articles = data.main.temp;
                }
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't use equal in the JS object syntax

```
data: {
    articles = ''
}
```

Comment: Right, I didn't notice that. Now I'm currently getting an error `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `this.$http`, use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library for making api calls.

Comment: I've just installed axios on dev my folder. Where do I usually place this three lines `import Vue from 'vue';`,
`import axios from 'axios';`,
`import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';`? Do include them inside my app.js?

Comment: can you create a plunker or fiddler for this. it would be easy to fix there.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
data: function() { 
    return () {
        articles: ‘’
    }
}
```

And specify http:// to the localhost

```
this.$http.get('http://localhost/aim-beta/rest/export/json/article'),
            function (data) {
                this.articles = data.json()
            }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting an error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"`

Answer (score 0):

Use this for the `data` JSON object:

```
data: {
     articles: ''
}
```

Then, use **Promise** for firing the HTTP request (note that I used the `http://` with the URL):

```
this.$http.get('http://localhost/aim-beta/rest/export/json/article')
          .then(function(response){
                this.articles = response.json();
          });
```

Source : [Documentation](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource)

Comment: Hi, I'm getting an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

Comment: try using `Vue.http.get` instead of `this.$http.get`. Then, let me know.

Comment: Hi, Same error on the console `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

Comment: Use this:

before creating your Vue app, add this line before -> `Vue.use(VueResource)`

Make sure you import the `vue-resource` : `import VueResource from 'vue-resource'`

Comment: Are you using any bundlers like `webpack` or `browserify`? Then, the above comment should work (Source : [Config Docs](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/config.md))

Comment: Not yet. Well I started my project by using the commands `vue init webpack project-name`